# RPM measurement using interrupt

Tags: microcontroller, motor, infrared, rpm

I am controlling the speed of the motor and measuring RPM using IR module.

The method I used works fine (I rotated the motor manually). I am facing problems when I connect the motor to the power supply. I just want to stop the motor once the speed reaches a certain limit. I am counting the pulses for 5 seconds, once the number of pulses crosses 11. I stop the motor.

However, when I provide voltage to the motor, the timer never reaches the end (overflows).

Power supply for motor: 48V.

```
//This code is for ATMEGA 16

#include<avr\io.h>
#include<avr\interrupt.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>

int del;
int x,x1,z,z1,a;
volatile int rpm;

int main (void){

DDRA = 0x00;
DDRD = 0xFF;
DDRC = 0xFF;    
DDRB = 0xFB;
ADCSRA = 0x87;
ADMUX = 0xC0;               // Selecting ADC0

TCNT1H = 0xAC;              //5 seconds timer for rpm
TCNT1L = 0x54;

TCCR1A = 0x00;
TCCR1B = 0x04;

MCUCSR = 0x40;
GICR = 0x20;                 //Enable interrupt 2
sei();

    while (1)
{   




    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
    while ((ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)) == 0);
    {
        x = ADCL;
        PORTD = x;
        x1 = ADCH;
        PORTC = x1;
        del = ADCL;
        del |= ADCH << 8;       //ADC value from pin 40 (throttle)
        del = (del-512)/50;  


        if (del >=7)
        {
            PORTB = 0x08;   // if throttle is completely turned, rotate at 
                            //full speed
        }           

        else if (del > 0)  //if throttle at midway, send PWM pulses 
                           //accordingly
        {
        PORTB = 0x08;
        _delay_ms(del);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        _delay_ms(10-del);
        }

        if (del < 0)
        {
        PORTB = 0x00;     //motor stopped when throttle is at initial 
                           //position
        }
    }


    if ((TIFR & (0x1<<TOV1)))    //if timer flag HIGH
    {   

        if (rpm >= 11)   // if rpm is greater than 11 during five seconds
        {
            PORTD = 0xAA;
            PORTB = 0x00;   //stop the motor
            PORTC = rpm;
            _delay_ms(2000);
            rpm = 0;
        }

        else               //else continue 
        {
        PORTD = 0xFF;
        PORTC = rpm;
        _delay_ms(1000);
        rpm = 0;
        }   


        TCCR1B = 0;      //restart the timer
        TIFR = 0x1<<TOV1;

        TCNT1H = 0xAC;
        TCNT1L = 0x54;

        TCCR1A = 0x00;
        TCCR1B = 0x04;
        PORTD = 0x00;
        PORTC = 0x00;

    }
    }
}

ISR (INT2_vect)
    {
        rpm++;
    }
```

IR sensor is at pin 3.
I am using the module as it is:https://www.amazon.in/VEEROBOT-Infrared-Proximity-Obstacle-Detecting/dp/B0115NCT4U/ref=sr_1_3?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1517231322&sr=1-3&keywords=ir+sensor

[image]

I am using this circuit to step the voltage down for Atmega16. hobby-hour.com/electronics/lm2576-5v-buck-regulator.png The mosfets work fine. I have already checked them with heavy load and long runs.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where am I going here? The timer doesn't overflow when I connect the motor to the supply. It works fine when the motor is not connected. The microcontroller and the motor have a separate power source.

Answer (score 2):

Your motor is creating back emfs that can cause your circuit to reset. You should, at the minimum, conect a reverse diode across the motor. This is not just standard practise but almost obligatory if you are to avoid damaging the MOSFET. Try adding a few power supply decoupling capacitor on the chips power rails too.

Voltage regulators also need input and output capacitors. If you actually have them fitted but felt that this detail was unimportant to show in your diagram then here begins your learning experience.

Comment: It is already there, but not in the circuit (sorry about that). I have connected IN5408. The power supply for motor is 48V.

Comment: I am using this circuit to step the voltage down for Atmega16. https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/lm2576-5v-buck-regulator.png

The mosfets work fine. I have already checked them with heavy load and long runs.

Comment: Why does your question's circuit say LM34 beside both regulators? Are you aware that omissions and mistakes just waste people's time?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was running some simulations earlier. I will fix it. The complete objective is much more than RPM counter. I will remove all the components that are redundant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make out, and it is really hard to decipher that code, you are using a rather odd method to measure the speed of the motor.

The normal method is to use the index pulse interrupt from the RPM sensor to capture the current value from a timer, then reset said timer ready for the next pulse interrupt. That way you can capture the time between pulses independently of the main routine and the latencies therein.

The main routine should then compare the current captured pulse period against the demand speed, using appropriate math, and modulate the drive appropriately to maintain the required pulse frequency.

Your current code seems to have big delays in there where you reset the RPM number AFTER those delays. How many interrupt happen during those delays that get thrown away... who knows.

Comment: The method I used works fine (I rotated the motor manually). I am facing problems when I connect the motor to the power supply. I believe that the back emf is too high and one IN5408 is not enough to deal with it and the code keeps resetting.

I just want to stop the motor once the speed reaches a certain limit. I am counting the pulses for 5 seconds, once the number of pulses crosses 11. I stop the motor.

Comment: @KanishakKatahra indeed, it COULD be that, but it is also quite likely that, when running at a controlled speed, your software routine and control method is failing.

Comment: I just want to stop the motor once the speed reaches a certain limit. I am counting the pulses for 5 seconds. Once the number of pulses crosses 1, I stop the motor. So it just an ON-OFF control.

Comment: @KanishakKatahra you really need to edit the question and describe in detail what you think that code is supposed to do. You are asking a bit much of the folks here to read that code and figure out what you intended. Weird things can and do happen with asynchronous control like you have.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should change my controller?

Comment: @KanishakKatahra I am suggesting your problem may be software, not hardware...

Comment: Thank you. But the simulations work as expected. And when I rotate the motor manually, I get the desired results. Once I supply voltage to the motor, the timer itself doesn't overflow.

Comment: @KanishakKatahra if you are not willing to listen to advice from those more experienced, why bother asking questions. Good luck to you.